# Artifactory upgrade failing due to DB conversion error

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to upgrade an Artifactory server but it seems to fail due to a DB conversion error.

```
2021-06-23T08:05:01.538Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [ae0b35be4a9501f6] [o.j.s.u.DbStatementUtils:62   ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Failed to execute query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNLOGGED"
  Position: 35:
ALTER TABLE distributed_locks SET UNLOGGED
2021-06-23T08:05:01.544Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [ae0b35be4a9501f6] [.s.d.v.c.DbSqlConverterUtil:94] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Could not convert DB using v225_alter_distributed_locks_set_unlogged converter due to ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNLOGGED"
  Position: 35
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNLOGGED"
  Position: 35
```

We are trying to upgrade from version 6.12.0 to the latest 7.19.9 (current latest).
Updates to later 6.x work ok...i'm currently up to 6.23.21 and attempts to 7.16.3 and 7.19.9 show the same DB migration error.
Attempts to update from earlier 6.x versions to other supported 7.x versions also show the same error.

We're running RHEL 7.9 and using RPM based installations...let me know if any more info is needed.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just to add, I aslo see this error.


2021-06-23T10:28:43.142Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [d9d37c2fa88cdd8d] [actoryContextConfigListener:91] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Failed initializing Artifactory context: Artifactory home not initialized.

Reading around this may be due to an error in the url in system.yaml. 
How do I know if this is the case..?

Its currently set to: url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/artifactory

Comment: Which PostgreSQL DB version are you using?

Comment: We have v9.2.24-6 - standard RHEL 7 RPM installation.

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory 7.19 supports Postgresql 9.5 and higher.

UBLOGGED table is supported since Postgresql 9.1, however ALTER table SET UNLOGGED is supported since Postgresql 9.5

Comment: Ok thanks for the info - I'll try upgrading.